# How can I free the memory taken up by Bitmap in .NET?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am working on some image related projects on .NET.
When I do:

```
while(true)
{
  Bitmap m = new Bitmap(100,100);
  m.Dispose();
}
```

The memory usage keeps going up. Why Dispose did not free all the memory used by Bitmap, and how can I actually free that piece of memory?

In my real work case, I can not reuse the exist Bitmap, because it might be in a different size every time it runs.
I also can not warp it with using, because Bitmap creation happens inside a methold and the result Bitmap is returned for further process.

EDIT:
It's strange I tried this exact same while true code but the memory usage seems to stop increasing fast. I just can not reproduce the situation(that it keept going up and up slowly and never fall back, at least in a few minutes)
Thanks for all your answers and I will pick the only answer I can pick as the solution.

Comment: Please don't do such a thing unless you want to crash the machine, even and especially on modern computers and preemptible operating systems ... 

Comment: The above works (if used in a real-world context, that means without while(true) loop). The garbage collector will eventually kick in and free memory, but this will typically happen in spikes. So memory will grow to some extend, then be reduced and start growing again.

Comment: Well here I guess it's like filling a pierced vase faster than water runs out, I suppose  

Comment: `while (true) { using (var bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100)) { } }`. How much does the memory usage grow? Excluding the initial allocation (when you see a bump in the Diagnostic Tools' chart and the Garbage Collector intervention a few moments later).

Comment: `The memory usage keeps going up.` How much does it go up, over what timeframe? And why on earth do you want to do that? Why create a new bitmap rather than reusing the old one?

Comment: Try to call System.GC.Collect() - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0#System_GC_Collect

```
while(true)
{
  Bitmap m = new Bitmap(100,100);
  m.Dispose();
  System.GC.Collect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant. .NET Runtime will do it for you when it "needs / wants" to.

If you'd like to have a "control" over the allocated memory, you're supposed to use unmanaged structures with pointers / unsafe.

Anyway, if you don't have any performance issues regarding to the code eg. insufficient memory - you should leave it as it is - runtime is going to free that memory in convenient time.

If you want to learn more about GarbageCollector and how memory is managed in .NET i can recommend you a book [https://www.amazon.com/Pro-NET-Memory-Management-Performance/dp/148424026X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/148424026X)